# Is there a limit on the number of labels that can be accessed via the API?

Tags: xero-api

I've got a 3rd party software from CDATA to download Xero data to Excel.  It has a max of 13 labels which can be downloaded.  This is fine for months.  Not fine for tracking categories.  ie we have a label per employee.  CDATA says it is a limitation of the Xero API.  That seems like a pretty basic error.

When I checked with CDATA they've said "not me guv".

Comment: Have you checked the Xero developer documentation to see if there actually is a limit on tracking category downloads? For example some Xero downloads provide less detail in some circumstances - if you try to download multiple invoices, you don't get as much detail as if you download an individual invoice. A bit more detail on exactly what you're trying to download from Xero might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a limitation on the Xero API. We recommend that you have less than 100 options in Xero itself but this is a soft limit.